# Is there a way to dynamically update scss variables using JS in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

**Problem**

I have two **scss variables** places in `colors.scss` file, I want to **update the variable colors only** from **javascript** based on a logic,

```
if(day){
  // update $backgroundColor to white
}else{
  // update $backgroundColor to black
}
```

**More info:**

I have tried `:export{}` which is not working and also `document.documentElement.style.setProperty` using global css variables. I am using **reactjs** for frontend development.

Comment: You can use the `classnames` package to help you manage scss classes in you javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can assign css variable to `$backgroundColor` as

```
:root {
  --background-color: white;
}
$backgroundColor: var(--background-color);
```

and update variable in js as

```
 const day = true;
 const root = document.documentElement;
 root.style.setProperty('--background-color', day ? 'white' : 'black');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't update **scss** variables since they are not exist in runtime (when JS is runs).

You can make 2 classes, one with each style, and apply one of the classes at runtime.

Comment: You are right in a way, we cannot update **scss** variables directly, thus having a css variable placeholder helps in dynamic updation.